# Event registration on dynamically added controls added in postback

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-4.0

I have a placeholder which I am adding some WebUserControls to. The WebUserControl only has a button in with an onClick.

```
<asp:Button ID="bMyButton" runat="server" OnClick="MyButtonOnClick" CausesValidation="false" />
```

When I add the WebUserControls to the page on Page_Load all works fine. The problem is that I have some filters do that post backs which call `ApplyFilters()`. I need to reload the items in this method based on the filters selected (the values of the filters haven't yet updated in the Page_Load event) but `MyButtonOnClick` event doesn't fire when I do this because they have been added to the page to late in the Life Cycle.

Anyone have any idea about a work around?

p.s I haven't pasted much code because I have simplified my example to explain what is happening during debugging. Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to "work around" this problem. Instead of relying on the ASP.NET events I am checking the values of my filters in `Request.Form[]`. That way I can see the new values of the filters before the control validation cycle and load the dynamic controls in `Page_Load`.

Not ideal as I would of preferred to stick to traditional events but I don't think there is any other way around this issue for now.